# How to minimize a running page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to minimize a running app in flutter like youtube does, so the user can scroll videos in youtube homepage while listening to the running video page:

Here's an example of the picture:
[image]

Comment: I think your page(which needs minimizing) must be `popup` route, after that you will just use `setState`, and change the width of the route.
see PopupRoute class docs.

Comment: Here is very good article about how to create your custom popup route.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-route-animations-6ea071be5168

Comment: Any example for the same would be great.

Comment: dude have you tried this https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer ?